# Where to put local git repository

Tags: git, svn, azure-devops

I'm converting to Git after working for several years with SVN. When working with SVN I had a "repos" directory on my server and individual directories within that for the individual projects (and hence where I would create the individual SVN repos). So I was very clear about my repo living on my server and I had a working copy on my local drive. All good.

The scenario I will now have is that I will be hosting some projects on Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) using Git. I understand that I have a remote repo and a local repo in this environment and that they are effectively clones. What about a local working directory? Do I still need this? I ask because I have seen posts that refer to running "git init" inside the local project directory, which tends to indicate that my hidden "git" directory will live within my local copy that I am working from. ie the working directory and the local repo are one in the same? Is this correct or best practice or should I still make a local repo directory for my local git repo and have a separate working directory?

I hope that makes sense. Please ask for any clarification.

Comment: It depends on your workflow.  If the only dev is you, you can set git up in your directory with git init and backup the .git directory every day/hour/etc.  If you're in a team, I'd suggest putting the repo in another location and having user clone from there.  If you need more details on  how to do that, hit me up and I can help out with more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ie the working directory and the local repo are one in the same?

This is not correct. the working directory is files you are editing and modifying, the local repo is a hidden directory, usually named as .git in the top level of your working directory.

Your local repo is used to keep your local modification history, which is the same as the repository you used with SVN. but git, as a distributed VCS, provide a set of mechanism to synchronize your local repo and the remote one.

Comment: Ok great .. that's the clarification I was after in that I can happily have .git in the top level of the project directory. Seems to make sense to have it at that location. Cheers